# Multiple Annotations from NSMutableArray in mapkit

Tags: ios, ipad, mkannotation, cllocation, mapkit

I have a mutablearray that is populated from sqlite db in ios.  I have gotten the  annotations to load and view properly. My question is how can I write a loop that will add annotations with the size of the array.  I have tried the following code and get and display the last entry in the array

```
NSMutableArray *annotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate5;
MyAnnotation* myAnnotation5=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < _getDBInfo.count; i++) {

    dbInfo *entity = [_getDBInfo objectAtIndex:i];

    NSNumber *numlat=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[entity.Latitude doubleValue]];
    NSNumber *numlon=[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[entity.Longitude doubleValue]];
    NSLog(@"%d",[_getDBInfo count]);
    la=[numlat doubleValue];
    lo=[numlon doubleValue];
    theCoordinate5.latitude=la;
    theCoordinate5.longitude=lo;

    myAnnotation5.coordinate=theCoordinate5;
    myAnnotation5.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"entity.EntityNo];
    myAnnotation5.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",entity.EntityName]; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation5];
    [annotations addObject:myAnnotation5];
}
```

I guess my question is how can I create and add to my view annotation objects based on the count in my array?

Any help is much appreciated.

I am new to iOS as well as programming so please be gentle.

Comment: What is `myAnnotation1`?  Are you expecting your `annotations` array to contain all the annotation objects you are adding to the map?

Comment: sorry put wrong line in code but has been edited now.  I have 6 obejects in my array but could be anywhere from 0 to 10.  I am trying to get an annotation for each object with out having to hard code each objectatindex

Comment: P.S.- The line 'myAnnotation5.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"entity.EntityNo]' shouldn't even compile without a comma (added in my answer). Please make sure that when asking a question you copy and paste your EXACT code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one `myAnnotation5` object.  When you set its `coordinate`, `title`, etc., you are setting it for that instance, which you happen to have added to `annotations` multiple times. Hence every entry in `annotations` will have the last set of properties you set - since every entry in `annotations` is actually the *same* object.

To remedy this, you need to create your `myAnnotation5` object anew each iteration of the loop, i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _getDBInfo.count; i++) {
    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation5=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    ...
    myAnnotation5.coordinate=theCoordinate5;
    myAnnotation5.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entity.EntityNo];
    myAnnotation5.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entity.EntityName];
    ...
    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation5];
}
```

Two asides:

1. I hope you are building with ARC, otherwise you are leaking memory left and right.
2. Since `MKMapView` has an `-annotations` property, there is likely little reason for you to keep your own `annotations` array - just keep a reference to `mapView`.

Comment: Thanks for the help worked perfect on the first try, and yes I am using ARC.

Comment: @charliejohnston Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: @ConradShultz I have a similar problem, would it be possible to assist me with my code? I am wanting to use a gesture to drop a pin annotation on my mapView. I have the code, but am unsure as to where to use it...

Comment: @cameron Please post your question on its own.

Comment: @ConradShultz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180298/drop-map-annotations-based-on-hold-gesture

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
MyAnnotation* myAnnotation5=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
```

to inside the for-loop just before setting the properties on `myAnnotation5`.

The way it is right now, you are creating only one `MyAnnotation` object and modifying its properties repeatedly.

Comment: Please have a look at this question as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396754/ios-custom-annotation-a-view-below-the-annotation-pin

Comment: @Anna please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330331/route-is-not-displaying-in-map