# MKMapView annotation with custom color AND visible title

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I know I can set a custom color for a `MKPinAnnotationView`.

I can also set the title for `MKAnnotationView` and it's visible without the need to be tapped.

But what I want is to have an annotation with both a custom color ***and*** a visible title (as opposed to taping the `MKPinAnnotationView` to show its title).

Is that possible?

Comment: For Objective-C, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415714/1271826.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the MKMAPViewDelegate and override this method below :

`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

inside this method just implement something like this :

```
 Avoid user location pin 
        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
            return nil
        } else {
    // HERE YOU CONFIGURE YOUR CUSTOM MKPinAnnotationView by also leveraging dequeue for performance
            let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

// YOUR CUSTOM VIEW you want to add instead of the default one
            let nibName = "MarkerView"
            let viewFromNib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MarkerView
            var annotationView: MarkerView?

            // if there is a view to be dequeued, use it for the annotation
            if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) as? MarkerView {

                if dequeuedAnnotationView.subviews.isEmpty {
// HERE YOU ADD IT AS A SUBVIEW
                    dequeuedAnnotationView.addSubview(viewFromNib)
                }
                annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            } else {

                let av = MarkerView(annotation: annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
                av.addSubview(viewFromNib)
                annotationView = av 
            }
    ...
    ...
 ////// ETC ETC of the configuration after regarding your annotation view
```

This should answer your issue.